# Creating an xsl converting xml with headers and footers for to another xml with xslt transformation,

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am a newbie in XSLT, I have an XML converted from csv file looks like below with Open and Close rows distict by text, type rows and value. They all come in with same record tags, 
 with distinction only in the string values itself

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Items>
<Row>
  <Transaction>Open</Transaction>
</Row>
<Row>
  <Transaction>Type plus</Transaction>
</Row>
<Row>
  <Transaction>A</Transaction>
</Row>
<Row>
  <Transaction>B</Transaction>
</Row>    
<Row>
  <Transaction>Close</Transaction>
</Row>
<Row>
  <Transaction>Open</Transaction>
</Row>
<Row>
  <Transaction>Type minus</Transaction>
</Row>
<Row>
  <Transaction>C</Transaction>
</Row>
<Row>
  <Transaction>D</Transaction>
</Row>    
<Row>
  <Transaction>Close</Transaction>
</Row>
...
...
...
...
...   
</Items>
```

I want the result to look as the following.I tried using a variable to store the using variable "Type" for storing plus or minus, but seems like I can't update the variable. Can anyone create an xsl which can do the transformation to the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result>
<message>
    <to>plus</to>
    <from>A</from>
</message>
<message>
    <to>plus</to>
    <from>B</from>
</message>
<message>
    <to>minus</to>
    <from>C</from>
</message>
<message>
    <to>minus</to>
    <from>D</from>
</message>
...
...
...
</result>
```

Comment: Can you use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9, XmlPrime, Altova?

Comment: Also do you really want the output to be a fragment of several top-level `message` elements without a root element?

Comment: It would also help if you showed a well-formed XML input snippet, currently all those `Transaction` elements are not properly closed.

Comment: Hi, @MartinHonnen I have edited the xml as your suggestion. Thanks that you noticed it

Comment: And what about the version fo XSLT you can use? Looks like a grouping problem to me that could be solved in XSLT 2 or later using `for-each-group group-starting-with`.

Comment: I am using xslt 1.0

Comment: Variables in XSL are **immutable** -- they cannot be changed once created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is rather ambiguous; what we need here is some clear rules.

If we assume that in each group of `Row`s starting with `<Transaction>Open</Transaction>`, the second `Row` contains the type and the last one closes the group, we can do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="grp" match="Row[not(Transaction='Open')]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Row[Transaction='Open'][1])" />

<xsl:template match="Items">
    <result>
        <xsl:for-each select="Row[Transaction='Open']">
            <xsl:variable name="group" select="key('grp', generate-id())" />
            <xsl:variable name="type" select="substring-after($group[1]/Transaction, 'Type ')" />
            <xsl:for-each select="$group[position() != 1 and position() != last()]">            
                <message>
                    <to>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$type"/>
                    </to>
                    <from>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Transaction"/>
                    </from>
                </message>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to obtain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
  <message>
    <to>plus</to>
    <from>A</from>
  </message>
  <message>
    <to>plus</to>
    <from>B</from>
  </message>
  <message>
    <to>minus</to>
    <from>C</from>
  </message>
  <message>
    <to>minus</to>
    <from>D</from>
  </message>
</result>
```

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k for your input. You are very close to the solution I needed. I just forgot to add some info in the xml. The incomng row with the transaction tag with indicates opening has some other text, but the position of the "open" substring is always the same. Simalarly for the transaction with close substring  Thinking something like  for   Row[not(Transaction='Open')] looking for something like substring(Transaction, 4,4)

Comment: So use `substring(Transaction, 4)='Open'` instead of `Transaction='Open'`.

Comment: Awesome ! thanks so much @michael.hor257k you saved tons of frustations, long hours of trying to figure this out.